# RedPark TTL Cable ReadBytesData - unable to get any data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, serial-port

I have two UILabels, info and receiving. Receiving is suppose to tell me that I am actually receiving data. However, when it does indicate that.... my info UILabel is not being updated accordingly. It sometimes works and sometimes does not work..

What is up with that?

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        [super viewDidLoad];

        receiving = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(30,50,255,100)];
        info = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(30,200,255,100)];

        info.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        receiving.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
//        [self.view addSubview: toggleSwitch];

        receiving.text = @"Not Receiving...";

        [self.view addSubview: info];
        [self.view addSubview: receiving];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) startCommThread:(id)object
{

//    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // initialize RscMgr on this thread
    // so it schedules delegate callbacks for this thread

    rcsMgr = [[RscMgr alloc] init];
    [rcsMgr setDelegate:self];

    // run the run loop
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

//    [pool release];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create and start the comm thread.  We'll use this thread to manage the rscMgr so
    // we don't tie up the UI thread.
    if (commThread == nil)
    {
        commThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                             selector:@selector(startCommThread:)
                                               object:nil];
        [commThread start];  // Actually create the thread
    }
}


- (void) readBytesAvailable:(UInt32)numBytes {

    receiving.text = @"Receiving...";
    NSString* str = [rcsMgr getStringFromBytesAvailable];
    if ( str ) receiving.text = @"I GOT SOMETHING!";
//    if ( numBytes ) receiving.text = numBytes;
    else receiving.text = @"Still Receiving...";
    info.text = str;

}
```

Comment: There's not enough information here for anyone to say much. However, the first thing that came to my mind, is is `-readBytesAvailable:` called on the main thread/queue?

Comment: Yes it is, it is being called on the main thread

Comment: To be honest. So far my project looks like this... 

http://makeprojects.com/Project/Connect+an+iPhone,+iPad,+or+iPod+touch+to+Arduino+with+the+Redpark+Serial+Cable/1130/1#.UQRR2aVZUts

But now I am trying to read characters with the serial port and it says that "I GOT SOMETHING" but nothing is appearing...

Comment: Have you run this in the debugger? Is `str` what you expect it to be after the call to `-getStringFromBytesAvailable`?

Comment: Where do i find this debugger? I am connecting the maple board's usb to the laptop to supply power and my iphone's TTL cable to the maple board... not sure how to debug this.

Otherwise, I expect str to have a string type. For eg. "123,123,123,123,"

Comment: Ahh, right, don't know what I was thinking. I mean using Xcode's debugger of course. So, you're stuck using NSLog statements then checking console output or similar debugging techniques. Still, the point is, you should see if `str` actually contains any data/the data you expect. No one can say what's actually going on by only looking at the code you've posted.

Comment: Thank you for the response so far. Please check my new edit version of what I have in my code...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best shot at an answer, with the caveat that I've never used RedPark's cable or SDK.  My hunch is that `-readBytesAvailable:` is called by the RscMgr on the same background thread used to set it up. You can't use UIKit objects on background threads. You need transfer that work back to the main thread/queue something like this:

```
- (void)readBytesAvailable:(UInt32)numBytes 
{
    NSString* str = [rcsMgr getStringFromBytesAvailable];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (str) {
            receiving.text = @"I GOT SOMETHING!";
        } else { 
            receiving.text = @"Still Receiving...";
        }
        info.text = str;
    });
}
```

Also, you should have an autorelease pool on your commThread. Why did you comment it out?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It didn't seem to meet my needs as it the problem persists.

Also, ARC is on, so it's not available.

Comment: With ARC on, set up an autorelease pool by surrounding the code in  `@autoreleasepool{}`. I'm afraid I can't offer any more help...

Comment: Seemed like the cable was the issue. Got another cable and everything seems to be working fine. Thank you so much for the help Andrew. :)

Comment: Good to hear :). I guess it's important to remember that hardware really can be defective sometimes.